# Setting individual entity properties based on list of entity properties

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, json.net

I have an intermediary object between my Entity Framework entities and a JSON object that I serialize/deserialize in order to import and export to a text file.

When I am exporting from the entity framework I use the following code to iterate through the entity types properties...If the property in the entity matches the property from an enum that I have, the property gets saved to the JSON object.  This stops entity specific properties from cluttering up my JSON.

```
var blockProperties = typeof(FixedLengthBlock).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var property in blockProperties)
{

    if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(ModuleSettingEnum)).Contains(property.Name.ToLower()) && property.GetValue((FixedLengthBlock)element, null) != null)
        blockJsonEntity.Properties.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue((FixedLengthBlock)element, null).ToString());
}
```

While the above code works, I cannot think of a similar way to do the opposite.  When reading back from JSON I have the properties/values in a dictionary.  I know that I can run through the properties of the EF Entity and search the dictionary if it contains a key like this:

```
var blockProperties = typeof(FixedLengthBlock).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var property in blockProperties)
{
        if (block.Properties.ContainsKey(property.Name))
   {
     ???????What goes here??????
   }
}
```

How do I get the matched property into the newly created entity I've made to receive the information.  I'd really like to avoid a large switch statement.

My Json object looks like this:

```
public class JsonEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
    public List<JsonEntity> SubEntities { get; set; } 

    public JsonEntity()
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is some relevant code missing here for those on the outside looking in to get a good picture of what entity you're serializing/deserializing into. In the section for `???????What goes here??????` are you trying to deserialize into the same type that you serialized from? If not, is there a map dictionary somehwere saying these properties map to these? Maybe it's a different type but the properties match exactly.

Comment: @BigM, I originally made a mistake in the code I copied onto here.  Yes, assume that I am trying to deserialize into the same entity I serialize into in the code above.  In this example, they are both 'FixedLengthBlock'.  'block' is a JsonEntity, so if the EF entity property matches a key in the JsonEntity I would like the value of that dictionary key-pair to be inserted into the corresponding EF property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so if we're deserializing into the same type let's try this:

```
var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
var blockProperties = typeof(FixedLengthBlock).GetProperties(bindingFlags);
var newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FixedLengthBlock))
foreach (var property in blockProperties)
{
    if (block.Properties.ContainsKey(property.Name))
    {
        var propertyInfo = newObj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name, bindingFlags);
        if (propertyInfo == null) { continue; }
        propertyInfo.SetValue(newObj, block.Properties[property.Name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  I only thing I had to add was a null parameter like so: propertyInfo.SetValue(newObj, block.Properties[property.Name], null);

Comment: @Scottingham, glad I could be of assistance!